# Targeting a button in a contact form

Tags: css

I have a button that I can't seem to target.

I tried using:

.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit {border-radius: 2px;}

Here is html:

```
 <p><label> Your Message<br />
 <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">. 
 <textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" 
 class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria- 
 invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7- 
 form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
 <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display- 
 none">.   </div></form></div>
 </div><!-- .entry-content -->
 <footer class="entry-footer">
  <span class="edit-link"><a
```

Comment: the class names dont have a dot (.) in front -> `.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit {border-radius: 2px;}`

Comment: Yeah. With dot. Without. Doesn't work

Comment: your html is not valid. Please validate your html and use indention. After that `.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {border-radius: 2px;}` (without space) should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```css
input.wpcf7-.form-control.wpcf7-submit{border-radius:2px;color:green; background:red;}
```

```html
<p><label> Your Message<br />
 <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">. 
 <textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" 
 class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria- 
 invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7- 
 form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
 <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display- 
 none">.   </div></form></div>
 </div><!-- .entry-content -->
 <footer class="entry-footer">
  <span class="edit-link"><a
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (notice the no space)

```
 .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {border-radius: 2px;}
```

Comment: Tried: input[type="submit"]{border-radius: 2px;} nothing either.

Comment: Alright then, please check concept of  specificity in css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity 
you can try to add more weight ie body .wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit or adding !important statement

Comment: Important is just an override function isn't it? There is nothing to override in wpcf7